# How to print out the last n minutes of rows before a specific row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a df with incidents and warnings and I would like to store the last 10 minutes of data that came before each incident in another df called "df1". I have added a boolean column to identify incidents in the df but I need a way to loop through the whole df and store the rows that occurred 10 minutes before each incident along with the incident itself.

for ex:

```
A                B                   Incident
warning      2018-11-01 01:37:12        F
warning      2018-11-01 01:37:41        F
warning      2018-10-31 01:37:48        F
warning      2018-10-30 01:40:31        F
warning      2018-10-29 01:43:41        F
warning      2018-10-28 01:45:51        F
incident     2018-10-27 01:47:41        T
```

In this case i would need to store

```
warning      2018-11-01 01:37:41        F
warning      2018-10-31 01:37:48        F
warning      2018-10-30 01:40:31        F
warning      2018-10-29 01:43:41        F
warning      2018-10-28 01:45:51        F
incident     2018-10-27 01:47:41        T
```

If there is another incident contained within the last 10 minutes of the first incident, I would like to use all the data before the second incident occurred. i.e., if no incident in last 10 mins, append df A, else append df B to df1.

Comment: If 2 incidents occur in the same interval?

Comment: @Corralien then If there are 2 incidents in the same interval, append the warnings up until the second interval to df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think that grouping records would be a good point to start.
I assume you need to retrieve subsets of records that occured within 10 minutes before "Incident" that is with "Incident" column set as "T".
Example "getting started" solution may look like this:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('your_set.csv', parse_dates=[1])
    all_rows = []
    within_accident_rows = []
    
    time = pd.Timedelta("10 min")
    
    incident_date = None
    incidents = df[df["Incident"] == 'T'].index # where incidents in dataset has occurred
    
    for idx in incidents:
        incident_date = df.iloc[idx]["B"]
        i = 1
        within_accident_rows.append(df.iloc[idx]["B"])
        while True:
            prev_row = df.iloc[idx - i]
            i += 1
            if incident_date - prev_row["B"] <= time and prev_row["Incident"] != 'T':
                within_accident_rows.append(prev_row["B"])
            else:
                all_rows.append(within_accident_rows)
                within_accident_rows = []
                break
```

It will group and collect all records (in `all_rows`) that occured within 10 minutes from incident or all records after previous accident (if previous incident was also within 10 minutes).

Comment: This adds just the time stamp of each record into all rows right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But with slight modificationyou can add entire rows (just append `prev_row` instead of `prev_row["B"]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to set the timestamp column as index, and use pandas' built-in datetimeindex slicing to select all rows within 10 minutes before the incident, with the help of `pd.Timedelta`.

One important thing to note however, is that this requires your datetimeindex to be sorted and in order. I noticed that your original data frame has days decreasing over rows while time increases. I assume that you meant for the data to be on the same day, but Excel smartfill extrapolated it differently.

Anyway, step by step code below. Setting up the data for our example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [
             "warning", "warning", "warning", 
             "warning", "warning", "warning", "incident"
         ],
    "B": [
        "2018-11-01 01:37:12", 
        "2018-11-01 01:37:41", 
        "2018-11-01 01:37:48", 
        "2018-11-01 01:40:31", 
        "2018-11-01 01:43:41", 
        "2018-11-01 01:45:51", 
        "2018-11-01 01:47:41",
    ],
    "Incident": ["F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "T"]
})
```

Setting datetimeindex:

```py
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(pd.Timestamp)
df = df.set_index("B")
df = df.sort_index()
```

You can select rows within a start and end time by specifying `df.loc[start:end]`. `start` and `end` should be `pd.Timestamp`s so that you can add / subtract time periods with `pd.Timedelta`.

```py
# Select timestamps of incidents
incident_df = df[df["Incident"] == "T"]
incident_ts = list(incident_df.index)

# Loop over timesteps, select relevant rows
selected_rows = []
for ts in incident_ts:
    selected_rows.append(df.loc[ts-pd.Timedelta("10 minutes"):ts])
    
# Concat into dataframe
selected_df = pd.concat(selected_rows)
```

The output is:

```sh
                            A Incident
B                                     
2018-11-01 01:37:41   warning        F
2018-11-01 01:37:48   warning        F
2018-11-01 01:40:31   warning        F
2018-11-01 01:43:41   warning        F
2018-11-01 01:45:51   warning        F
2018-11-01 01:47:41  incident        T
```